# How do I install psycopg2 on Azure app service Windows web app?

Tags: python, postgresql, azure

I am deploying onto Azure app services. The application settings are: Windows host, 32-bit and Python 3.4. I have got everything else working, but when I tried to switch to using a Postgres DB then I ran into an issue. When pip tries to install the requirements from requirements.txt, it fails to install psycopg2. The error is:

```
> env\scripts\pip install psycopg2
D:\home\site\wwwroot
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
  Running setup.py (path:D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\psycopg2\setup.py) egg_info for package psycopg2
    Error: pg_config executable not found.
```

Apparently this is because it is attempting to compile the pg library, but I don't understand why it is trying to compile when there are wheels listed on the pypi page that claim to be for cp34-win32.

I have tried committing the wheel to the repository and then directly installing the wheel during deployment (`env\scripts\pip install wheelhouse\psycopg2-2.7.1-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl` via deploy.cmd) but this results in this error:

```
> env\scripts\pip install wheelhouse\psycopg2-2.7.1-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl
D:\home\site\wwwroot
psycopg2-2.7.1-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Storing debug log for failure in D:\home\pip\pip.log


> type D:\home\pip\pip.log
D:\home\site\wwwroot
------------------------------------------------------------

D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\scripts\pip run on 07/22/17 17:47:25

psycopg2-2.7.1-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Exception information:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main

    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 257, in run

    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))

  File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 167, in from_line

    raise UnsupportedWheel("%s is not a supported wheel on this platform." % wheel.filename)

pip.exceptions.UnsupportedWheel: psycopg2-2.7.1-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: try wheel x64 package???

Answer (score 1):

The issue stems from the fact that the version of Python 3.4 that Azure provides is very old. The version of pip that is available is not new enough to install the psycopg2 wheel successfully. Trying to run `pip install -U pip` was no help. It resulted in a corrupted pip install and the env folder had to be deleted and recreated.

My work around for this issue is to install Python 3.6.1 32-bit as an "Extension". The extensions are available in the left pane of the web app settings in Azure, and allow one to select any version of Python. Once the extension is activated, a new Python folder becomes available in D:\home\python36 (for example). From there, running `pip install psycopg2` works without any issue.

The only remaining pain is that I couldn't get virtualenv to run using the new Python 3.6, so I had to rejig the deployment script (deploy.cmd) and the web.config to refer to the Python executable in D:\home\python36 instead of D:\home\wwwroot\env\scripts. Also removed a bunch of the logic in deploy.cmd that detects the requirements.txt and runtime.txt as that boilerplate logic is not necessary.